# Why I get java.util.ConcurrentModificationException error?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask

I'm having troubles with this code:

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Example> examples){
        for(Example i : examples)
        {
            customAdapter.add(i);
        }
        listExamples.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }
```

where listExamples it's a `ListView` that I have in my mainActivity layout.

The error that it gives to me it's the `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` error. I know that it happens when you modify, for example, an ArrayList inside the loop but here I don't really modify my ArrayList of values. I just add the objects of `Example` into my CustomAdapter (which is not iterating in the loop).

Note: As you can see, this code it's wrap in the onPostExecute part of my `AsynkTask` method.

I look on the Internet questions and here in Stackoverflow but I coudn't solve my problem. In all the questions that I have seen I see that they have an ArrayList that they are modifying inside the loop, but it is not my case.

If any of you have idea about how to solve it or if I'm wrong with the concepts that I put above please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** The stack trace of my log console (I simplified it by post only the Error logs)

```
06-05 02:22:31.891  24678-24678/ccom.example.user.project E/﹕ appName=com.example.user.project, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
06-05 02:22:31.891  24678-24678/com.example.user.project E/﹕ 0
06-05 02:22:31.891  24678-24678/com.example.user.project E/﹕ appName=com.example.user.project, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
06-05 02:22:31.891  24678-24678/com.example.user.project E/﹕ 0
06-05 02:22:32.953  24678-24678/com.example.user.project E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.user.project, PID: 24678
    java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
            at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
            at com.example.user.project.MainActivity$chargeExample.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:192)
            at com.example.user.project.MainActivity$chargeExample.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:131)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT 2:** Here is my `asynktask` method and the code in `doInBackground()`

```
class chargeExample extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, ArrayList<Example>> {
        protected void onPreExecute(){
        }
        protected ArrayList<Example> doInBackground(Void... params) {

            String url = "url of my GET method of my API REST";

            HttpGet method = new HttpGet(url);

            method.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

            try{
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(method);
                String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                JSONArray responseJSON = new JSONArray(responseString);
                for(int i=0; i<responseJSON.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject object = responseJSON.getJSONObject(i);

                    int idMain = object.getInt("idMain");
                    String date = object.getString("date");
                    String name = object.getString("name");
                    double value = object.getDouble("value");
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd");
                    Date datePar = sdf.parse(date);

                    examp.add(new Example(idMain, datePar, name, value));
                }
            }catch(Exception ex){
                Log.e("ServicioRest", ex.toString());
            }
            return examp;
        }
```

Comment: This error can occur if you modify the list on another thread. A way of preventing this will be to access the list in a `synchronized` block, eg: `synchronized(examples){...}`, you may have to do the same for the `customAdapter`.

Comment: How is it that your stack trace shows two different invocations of the same `onPostExecute()` method, but the code you posted does not contain any recursive invocation, and anyway is not long enough to explain the line numbers in the trace?  Simplifying the problem is great, but post whatever error accompanies *the problem you posted*.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the line 192 refers to the line in which I define my loop `for(Example i : examples)` and the line 131 in which I define the Asynktask `class chargeExample extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, ArrayList<Example>> {`

Comment: @Error404, that explanation is not consistent with the actual stack trace, but perhaps we can figure out what's *really* going on if you give us the code in the vicinity of line 131.

Comment: @JohnBollinger what do you need? My asynktask function?

Comment: The joys of multithreading try 
synchronized(examples){
 for(Example i : examples)
        {
            customAdapter.add(i);
        }}

Comment: Right now I need the code at and around line 131 of `MainActivity.java`, as I said.  I have no idea what method that is, *since I do not have the code*.

Comment: @RQuijano it crashes too.

Comment: @Error404 you need to synchronize on that object every time you access it, not just in that method.

Comment: And which is the line 131 referenced by the stack trace?

Comment: Did you use the `examp` list when you've created the `customAdapter` object ? If so, this line `customAdapter.add(i);` will actually modify the underlining `ArrayList<>` (`examp`) used by the adapter, which means that you are modifying the list while you iterate it, hence the exception.

Comment: @JohnBollinger to the first line of the AsynkTask `class chargeExample extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, ArrayList<Example>> {`

Comment: @Titus I use my `customAdapter` into my `examp` list, yes. How can I solve it? Or what I should investigate for?

Comment: You may try to replace `ArrayList` with [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) as this does not throw ConcurrentModificationExceptions while iterating over it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments it seems that the list you are iterating over `examples` is the same list that backs the `customAdapter` adapter, which means that when you add/remove items from `customAdapter` the items will also be added/removed from the list that `examples` refers to. In this case, to prevent the exception, you can do something like this:

```
class chargeExample extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, ArrayList<Example>> {
    protected void onPreExecute(){
    }
    protected ArrayList<Example> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<Example> newList = new ArrayList<Example>();
        String url = "url of my GET method of my API REST";

        HttpGet method = new HttpGet(url);

        method.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

        try{
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(method);
            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            JSONArray responseJSON = new JSONArray(responseString);
            for(int i=0; i<responseJSON.length(); i++){
                JSONObject object = responseJSON.getJSONObject(i);

                int idMain = object.getInt("idMain");
                String date = object.getString("date");
                String name = object.getString("name");
                double value = object.getDouble("value");
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd");
                Date datePar = sdf.parse(date);

                newList.add(new Example(idMain, datePar, name, value));
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e("ServicioRest", ex.toString());
        }
        return newList;
    }
```

and in the `onPostExecute(...)`

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Example> examples){
    for(Example i : examples)
    {
        customAdapter.add(i);
    }
    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```